# Does every Lie algebra come from commutator of some associative product operation?

Tags: abstract-algebra, representation-theory, lie-algebras

Suppose $\mathfrak{g}$ is an Lie algebra. Is it possible to define an associative product operation $\star$ on $\mathfrak{g}$ such  that $[A,B]=A\star B - B \star A$ ?  If it is not possible to do so in general, how do we know which Lie algebras come as commutator of some product operation ? (Are there any useful criteria ?)

I am aware (without proof) that every Lie algebra has an embedding $f$ into an associative algebra such that the Lie bracket $[A,B]$ corresponds to $f(A)f(B)-f(B)f(A)$,but the question that I ask above demands something stronger.

Comment: I think the universal enveloping algebra satisfies your criteria: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_enveloping_algebra.  Look at the "Direct Construction" section.

Comment: @AdamSaltz Thanks! This solves my question. Could you please give a reference (other than the ones given on wikipedia page and preferably a book) where I could read more about universal enveloping algebras ?

Comment: I don't think it solves the problem, since the universal enveloping algebra is built on a much larger space than the Lie algebra.  For sl_2, say, you want a three-dimensional associative algebra whose commutator is the Lie product.  It seems wildly implausible that this is possible for general Lie algebras without being advertised along with the PBW theorem, and I would expect instead a strong No-Go theorem that it is generally not possible except in extremely special cases.

Comment: @user90041 I learned about them from Kassel, Rosso, and Turaev's Quantum Groups and Knot Invariants and also Hong and Kang's Quantum Groups and Crystal Bases.

Comment: @zyx I think you are right.  Thank you.

Comment: Do we insist that $\star$ be bilinear?

Comment: @user90041: Is your Lie algebra finite dimensional? Have you heard of Ado's theorem? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ado%27s_theorem

Comment: @PinkElephants I did not think about this before posting the question. I would prefer an answer in both cases : when we require $\star$ to be bilinear and when we do not.

Comment: @rafaelm We can assume that $g$ is finite dimensional. But does Ado's theorem solve my question ? Sorry, I am unable to see this immediately.

Comment: @user90041: I'm not sure myself, but I thought it might be useful. With Ado's theorem you can assume without loss of generality that your $\mathfrak g$ is subspace of matrices and operation is matrix commutator. Unfortunately the problem still remains, your subspace might not be closed under matrix multiplication.

Comment: @zyx I think I now understand your point. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer is no in general, and I suspect it's no for all simple Lie algebras.  Here's an argument that works for many simple Lie algebras including $\mathfrak{sl}_2$.  (Dollars to doughnuts there's a more direct elementary proof for $\mathfrak{sl}_2$.)

Suppose that $\mathfrak{g}$ is a non-commutative Lie algebra which arises as the commutators for some algebra.  Then there's a map of $\mathfrak{g}$-modules $\mathfrak{g} \otimes \mathfrak{g} \rightarrow \mathfrak{g}$ given by multiplication $x \otimes y \mapsto xy$ and another map given by opposite multiplication $x \otimes y \mapsto yx$.  Since $\mathfrak{g}$ is non-commutative these two maps are linearly independent, so $\dim \mathrm{Hom}_{\mathfrak{g}\text{-mod}}(\mathfrak{g} \otimes \mathfrak{g}, \mathfrak{g}) \geq 2$.  So any non-commutative Lie algebra with the property that $\dim \mathrm{Hom}_{\mathfrak{g}\text{-mod}} (\mathfrak{g} \otimes \mathfrak{g}, \mathfrak{g}) = 1$ cannot come from an associative algebra.  Examples include $\mathfrak{sl}_2$ and all simple Lie algebras outside the A series.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on why ${\sf dim}({\sf Hom}({\mathfrak g} \otimes {\mathfrak g}, {\mathfrak g})=1)$ when ${\mathfrak g}$ is a simple algebra ? By e.g. giving a reference.

Comment: @EwanDelanoy: It's just a calculation that you do seperately in every case.  For $\mathfrak{sl}_2$ you should be able to check it easily by hand.  For other simple Lie algebras the calculation is harder.  It's certainly in [Bird Tracks](http://birdtracks.eu) and for the BCD series it should be in Fulton-Harris.  I know it from Vogel's uniform formula for decomposing $\mathfrak{g} \otimes \mathfrak{g}$ e.g. at the end of [this paper](http://www.math.jussieu.fr/~vogel/grenoble-99b.pdf).

Comment: See also this MO question: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/129857/relating-two-characterizations-of-mathfrak-sl-n-2-among-simple-lie-alge/129911#129911

Answer (score 4):

The answer is indeed *no* for all semisimple Lie algebras. Such an associative product would determine a left-symmetric and a right-symmetric structure on the Lie algebra. It is known that this cannot exist for semisimple Lie algebras over a field of characteristic zero because of Whitehead's lemma. In fact, there is no left-symmetric structure. If $L$ denotes the Lie algebra, the left-multiplication defines an $L$-module $M_L$ which must satisfy $H^1(L,M_L)=0$. Since the identity $id$ is a $1$-cocylce of $L$ with values in $M$, it must be a coboundary, i.e., there exists an element $e$ such that the right-multiplication $R(e)$ by $e$ is the identity. Because of $[L,L]=L$ however, all right multiplications have zero trace. Hence the identity has zero trace - a contradiction.